# Is There Any Reason to Use HX Tags When I Override All Styles Anyway?

Tags: html, css

I use `<h1>`, `<h2>`, `<h3>` tags for headers.  But then I almost always "overwrite" pretty much all styles (font size/family/weight, margin and padding).

Given this, is there any real reason to use them, other than their somewhat informative nature (that something is meant as a heading)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any real reason to use them, other than their somewhat informative nature

That is the ONLY reason to use them, to describe your document. That's the whole point of HTML, CSS is meant purely for styling.

There are exceptions for the non-semantic tags like `div` and `span`, but generally what you plan to do with your CSS should never affect your decisions on which tag to use to mark up your content, always use the appropriate one.

Comment: Yep, your HTML should be understandable as is, the CSS is for styling.  http://gsnedders.html5.org/outliner/ gives you a good idea of why H tags are useful.

Comment: Yeah I was looking at some links to send the OP about document outlines, http://html5doctor.com/outlines/ Good rule of thumb: HTML describes what content IS, CSS describes what it LOOKS LIKE - don't mix them up.

Comment: And JS describes what a document does. All those lines blur frequently (`target='_blank'` in HTML, `:target` selector in CSS or adding styling with JS are some examples), but ideally 99% of the time the separation should be observed.

Comment: “Describing a document” is a purely abstract concept and does not address the question about real reason.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: That's fundamental HTML, even wikipedia describes this accurately. Each tag has a meaning that is completely irrelevant to how/if you style it with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a good to define **heading** tags in your document. There are some good reason like

```
It's good to describe your document

It's good for SEO also

It's good to use heading tag when a screen reader set to a scanning mode.
```

Read this for more http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/headings_struct.htm

Answer (score 1):

Heading markup is known to be significant to search engines (they give greater relative weight to text in them than copy test), though the details (including the importance of this issue) are not public information. Some screen readers and assistive software make use of heading markup, e.g. allowing “heading reading mode” and by making noticeable pauses before and after a heading. When an HTML document is opened in Microsoft Word, heading elements are recognized as headings that are used e.g. in generating a table of content. Headings are a widely known concept, so user style sheets may conceivably have settings for them, suitable for an individual user.

This description is not exhaustive, but it illustrates that for heading elements, the idea of “semantic markup” has some practical relevance.

Comment: Even screen readers can have "styles" described by aural stylesheets, so that point seems irrelevant to me. Not that I disagree with your post, but it's no different than a normal web browser's visual styles in that respect. You don't use a heading simply because you want a "pause" when the document is read, you simply use it if the content **is** a heading - how the user agent *may* read or display it should have no significance.